# Define variable of checkbox - always null

Tags: javascript, variables, checkbox, toggle

I am trying to get the state (True/False/null etc) of my "CSS-only" toggle switch. However I only ever get null. I can't work out why it is, only that for whatever reason the checkbox input is not behaving in its default manner.

```
  <div class="container">
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" id="switch">
      <span class="switch-label" data-on="External" data-off="Internal" id="switch"></span>
      <span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
<button id="btn">Alert</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
// Get the checkbox
  var message_type = document.getElementById("switch.value");
     alert(message_type);
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value is a property, `document.getElementById("switch").value` would return the value (if there was any), but it would return always the same, use `document.getElementById("switch").checked`. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all 2 elements on you page have the same id `switch` : input and span. For DOM elemets there is a rule that id should be unique for every elements.

In your query: `var message_type = document.getElementById("switch.value");` you are trying to get element by id `switch.value` literally

So, imagine situation that only input has unique id `switch` you can get its value using:

```
document.getElementById("switch").value
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("switch").checked
```